# AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm - AWS CloudFormation - not working for multiple Dimensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, cloudwatch-alarms

I created an AWS CloudWatch Alarm that monitors multiple Lambda functions and triggers in case of error in any Lambda.

Alarm is working as expected if there is only one Lambda function (`Dimensions`)

```
Dimensions:
      - Name: FunctionName
        Value: invoice-lambda-function
```

In case of multiple Lambda functions (`Dimensions`) it's erroring while creating the CloudFormation Stack

```
Dimensions:
      - Name: FunctionName
        Value: invoice-lambda-function
      - Name: FunctionName
        Value: bill-lambda-function
      - Name: FunctionName
        Value: payment-lambda-function
```

Error:
`Dimension names must be unique (duplicate: FunctionName) (Service: AmazonCloudWatch; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: ca4d0fb5-5f7c-48d1-a49e-3012f294655e; Proxy: null)`

**AWS CloudFormation Template**

```
ErrorNotificationAlarm:
  Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'
  Properties:
    AlarmDescription: Send error notification
    Namespace: AWS/Lambda
    MetricName: Errors
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
    EvaluationPeriods: '1'
    Period: '60'
    Statistic: Sum
    Threshold: '0'
    AlarmActions:
    - !Ref ErrorTopic
    Dimensions:
      - Name: FunctionName
        Value: invoice-lambda-function
      - Name: FunctionName
        Value: bill-lambda-function
      - Name: FunctionName
        Value: payment-lambda-function
  ErrorTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: ErrorTopic
  ErrorTopicSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Endpoint: xxxxx@gmail.com
      Protocol: email
      TopicArn: !Ref ErrorTopic
```

- Is my Syntax correct?
- Doesn't the Alarm work for multiple similar (`FunctionName`) Dimenions?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use three same dimensions equal to `FunctionName`. If you want to summarize multiple metrics for different functions you have to use [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) to aggravate the metrics from the three functions into a single metric.